# C queue implementation using void* - good or bad practice?

Tags: c, pointers, queue, void

I have implemented a basic queue structure in C using void pointers. The procedure is as follows:

- initializing the structure - I set the size of the variable type to be stored in the queue
- push - I pass the pointer to the variable to be stored, the queue then grabs a copy for itself
- front - the structure returns a void* to the element in front. I may just grab the pointer, or `memcpy()` it to have a local copy.

The struct itself looks like this:

```
struct queue
{
    void* start;    //pointer to the beginning of queue
    void* end;      //-||- to the end
    size_t memsize; //size of allocated memory, in bytes
    size_t varsize; //size of a single variable, in bytes
    void* initial_pointer;      //position of the start pointer before pop() operations
};
```

start and end are just void pointers that point to some location within the currently allocated memory block. If I push elements on the queue, I increment the end pointer by `varsize`. If I pop(), I just decrement the end pointer also by `varsize`.

I don't think I should post the functions code here, it's over 100 lines.

**The question:** is this considered a good or a bad practice? Why (not)?

Note: I'm aware that there are many other options for a queue in C. I'm just asking about the quality of this one.

EDIT: The implementation is available here:
http:// 89.70.149.19 /stuff/queue.txt   (remove the spaces)

Comment: Use size_t for memory sizes

Comment: I think its good to write generic code using `void*`

Comment: `void*` is certainly ok.  A `union` would be more ideal though.

Comment: Comes to mind after discussion below, you mean a stack data structure, not a queue, don't you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's OK to use `void *` if you don't know the type and size of the objects to be stored in the queue (in fact, the C standard library follows the same approach, see the `memcpy()` and `qsort()` functions for some examples). However, it would be better to use `size_t` (or `ssize_t` if you need a signed data type) for specifying the size of the elements stored in the queue.

Comment: Ran Eldan mentioned that already, I have corrected it. OK, thank you for your opinion. I actually think it's intuitive to do that, only I've seen some people claiming this is "ugly".

Comment: @szczurcio The thing is that you can't really do anything else if you don't know the type beforehand. If you do, then don't use `void *` by any means for better type safety.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't show us enough to be sure about your implementation. `void*` for the user data items is fine, you can't do much otherwise in C.

But I strongly suspect that you have an internal list element type that you use to manage the individual items, something like

```
struct list_item {
  struct list_item* next;
  void* data;
};
```

If that is the case and your `start` and `end` pointers are pointing to such elements, you definitively should use your element type in the `struct queue` declaration:

```
struct queue
{
    struct list_item* start;    //pointer to the beginning of queue
    struct list_item* end;      //-||- to the end
    size_t memsize; //size of allocated memory, in bytes
    size_t varsize; //size of a single variable, in bytes
    struct list_item* initial_pointer;      //position of the start pointer before pop() operations
};
```

For this to work you don't even have to expose the definition of `struct list_item` to the user of `struct queue`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. start and end are just void pointers that point to some location within the currently allocated memory block. If  I push elements on the queue, I increment the end pointer by varsize. If I pop(), I just decrement the end pointer also by varsize.

Comment: @szczurcio, is a very unconventional implementation of a queue, the usual one would be something with dynamic elements as I describe it here. You should add the description that you have in your comment to the question, for reference. I would then delete this answer, which doesn't serve you much.

Comment: OK, done. But I still don't understand what do you mean by a "conventional" implementation. Could you please explain?

Comment: @szczurcio, "conventionally" lists are implemented in C as a dynamic data structure that is composed of individual items as my `list_item` that links through a chain of references. At a first thinking, yours will have to readjust the size and perhaps start position of the array of elements that you keep behind the scenes. This might be profitable in certain cases, I don't know. I have seen people using such arrays for stack implementations, but not for queues.